# Why does init need two arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm probably missing something obvious here. With the following code:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

that = Thing()
```

I get the error 'init needs two arguments'. I thought 'self' was one of the arguments and when I try to instantiate the object by putting the name inside the parentheses I get other errors.

Comment: "when I try to instantiate the object by putting the name inside the parentheses I get other errors." - And your conclusion is that you should *not* put the name in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your `__init__` takes two arguments: `self`, and `name`.  When you call `Thing()`, `self` is passed implicitly, but you still need to pass the second one explicitly, like `Thing("name")`.  If you're still getting an error when doing that, that's a different story.  You should post that error as well.

(And I doubt the error says "init needs two arguments".  It would have been more helpful to include the actual error message...)

Comment: I did 'Thing("name")' and didn't get an error. However, that was a model program; in the real program I tried the same thing and DID get an error. Now I must figure out why there's a difference.

Comment: @mistermarko: so in code you haven't shown which differs from your example in some way you haven't explained you have an error you haven't quoted?

Comment: Sorry, should have had lunch first.

Comment: The correct answer: that = Thing("that"). This is the best way to instantiate an object because the public and internal names are the same. The constructor must have the form __init__(self, name):, self.name = name. I haven't seen this trick stated anywhere.

Comment: @mistermarko: Public and internal names? You're mixing up some ideas in your head and the result is ... wrong.

Comment: Do you know a better way of giving an object a name?

Comment: Matthias: I just looked at YOUR answers - you used the SAME technique! (foo = Referencer('foo'))